# php header redirect before database insert

Tags: php, header

My php `header("Location: example.com")` seems to redirect before the database query is inserted (on one computer). Which imo is weird, because I check if the database returns true before header runs.

This works fine for me, but on my friends system it seems to redirect too early. If I remove the `header()` function and `die()`. It inserts fine.

This is coded as an Extension to mediawiki. I dont know if the problem lies here. Mediawiki has its own database query class and functions.

```
if ($_GET['action'] == 'postReply') {
    $threadid = $_POST['t_id'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $postReply = postThreadReply($threadid, $username, $userid, 
$content);
    if ($postReply == 1) {
        header("Location: ?title=" . $title . "&t=" . $threadid . '#last');
        die();
    }
```

This code is adapted to be read easier.

This is the main function which the header redirects too early.
postThreadReply() do some checks and inserts into the correct tables. `postThreadReply()` returns 1 if each query returns true.

I don't think more code is necessary, but let me know if it is. :)

So I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my code, or within Mediawiki? Or is this a known issue with the `header()` function? Is there any alternative method I can try?

This is my first question here, so I'm sorry if my question is unclear or I dont provide enough code.

EDIT:

postThreadReply()

```
function postThreadReply($threadid, $username, $userid, $t_post) {
    if (postExistDuplicate($threadid, $username, $userid, $t_post)) return 3;
    if (!threadExist($threadid)) return 4;
    $inpost = insertPost($threadid, $username, $userid, $t_post);
    if (!$inpost) return 2;
    return 1;
}
```

insertPost()

```
function insertPost($threadid, $username, $userid, $t_post) {
$datetime = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dbw = wfGetDB( DB_MASTER );
$res = $dbw->insert( 
    'disc_posts', 
    array(
        'id' => null,
        'thread_id' => $threadid,
        'author' => $username,
        'author_id' => $userid,
        'content' => $t_post,
        'posted' => $datetime,
        'deleted' => 0
    )
);
return $res;
```

}

^ Mediawikis way of doing queries.

Comment: can you show us the code for postThreadReply?

Comment: @KasiaGogolek Added the code now. It mostly calls other functions tho.

Comment: I can also add that this problem occurs on the function to postThread and reportThread. which is somewhat similar to the above